# The property 'TickFrequency' was not found in type 'Slider'

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, slider

I have the following XAML on Windows Phone 8:

```
 <Slider x:Name="slider" TickFrequency="1" SmallChange="1" LargeChange="1"  Minimum="0" Maximum="10" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="26,208,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="195" ValueChanged="Slider_ValueChanged"/>
```

And errors are:

1) `The property 'TickFrequency' was not found in type 'Slider'`

2) `The property 'TickFrequency' does not exist on the type 'Slider' in the XML namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation'.`

3) `The member "TickFrequency" is not recognized or is not accessible.`

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like you have to have TickPlacement set to something other than 'None' for the tick marks to show.  Not sure if this would make that error.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.slider.tickfrequency

The drawing of tick marks on a slider depends on both the TickFrequency and TickPlacement properties. In order for tick marks to be shown, you must set the TickFrequency property to a value greater than 0, and the TickPlacement property to a value other than None.

```
  xmlns:uc="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls"
```

Comment: 'TickPlacement' is not recognized as well

Comment: Do you have any other errors on the page,  Odd things like this generally mean something else mostly unrelated is causing the problem

Comment: there are no errors, I even created a new project and pasted only this line in XAML and still the same problem

Comment: and you have the right references       Namespace:  System.Windows.Controls
Assembly:  PresentationFramework (in PresentationFramework.dll)?

Comment: I have `using System.Windows.Controls`. How to reference Assembly?

Comment: under you project, there should be a References section.  Right click and 'Add Reference' should work.

Comment: I was looking for a PresentationFramework.dll but couldn't find the one for .NET Framework 4.5 Do you know where I can get it?

Comment: When you brought up the Add References dialog, you looked under Assemblies then Framework?  So you saw older versions but not the 4.5?  This is something that should have been installed with the 4.5 framework.

Answer (score 0):

You can try [this](https://xamarinexperience.blogspot.com/2019/03/how-to-add-tick-marks-on-sliders-in.html)for xamarin forms slider, for android and iOS apps. It does not require a custom renderer as well.